# How do I get my hands on higher-tier equipment and magic in Tactics Ogre (PSP)?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

I've finished a play-through of Tactics Ogre and as a completionist have been using the World Tarot to go back and complete the other routes (e.g. Law route) to recruit more characters. My party members are all level 28-30 and have equipment and magic that I have been able to purchase since Chapter IV (e.g. Siege Bow, Baldur Daggers, Brigandine, Heal III).

All of the enemies scale to be the same level as your party, and I've noticed that their equipment, skills and magic seem to be related to their level. This means that the enemies are using weapons like 'Frost Bow', 'Wyrmscale' armor and spells like Judgement III while I'm stuck with the equipment I got almost 10 levels ago. It's not getting difficult yet, but I imagine that if I continue to level up, the enemies will eventually have access to things that I can't keep up with.

What is the best way to get my hands on stronger equipment and magic? I've had a Holy Comet and Roodbow drop after playing for about 8 hours but that was all, and I won't be able to gear everyone up properly if it's that inefficient to get decent gear. It seems like there must be a secret shop somewhere or some other more logical method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything beyond ~Level 20 equipment, there are three ways to go about getting it:

1. Craft it yourself
2. Recruit characters that have it.
3. Steal it from them

Recruiting characters and stealing are the easy ways to go about it, but you need luck to spawn enemies that have equipment you want; there's no reliable way to ensure certain items, I'm afraid.

If you DO manage to find equipment to your liking, you want to hurt them, and move Denim directly behind them for your best chance at recruiting them.  Just like hit chance, being behind them is better than being in front of them or to their side.  And the less health they have, the better chance you have as well.

For stealing, you want your Rogue class as high a level as possible, and be in the same spot as Denim would be for recruiting.  That'll give you your best chance at stealing equipment.

The more reliable (and much, MUCH more tedious) method is crafting.  Once you get the recipe books, you can start the process of crafting better equipment.  Much of them will even improve your existing equipment, such as Baldur +1 or Superior equipment.  That will use the base item in the recipe as well.  You can craft equipment straight up into level ~32 with the complete collection.

The recipe books are acquired as you go through the story, and I believe some of the rarer Enchidrions are gotten by fulfilling certain requirements and running through Hell's Gate.  You can find a guide for their locations [here at GameFAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/999440-/58482035).  Once you've gotten them, though, that's when the real tediousness starts.  Crafting success is based on your overall level, I believe, and if you fail, you lose your crafting items.  And you can only make **one** item at a time.  And several of the best equipment requires four items, and each of *those* items require crafting as well.  And failure can happen at any point, so be prepared to spend a decent chunk of time crafting the materials.

I spent the vast majority of my cash throughout the game buying the related base materials, and then crafting them into the items needed for equipment, and then crafting the equipment itself.  It's tedious, but it's the most reliable way to get the best equipment possible.

As for magic, I found [this guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N057JKdekbJ5v0uGrCzdRMqEy1Rkfcyo2bPpvMZi8f0/edit?hl=en_US) where you can find certain spells.  Essentially, the more advanced spells are usually random drops towards the end of the game.  There IS a secret shop, Deneb's, that shows up in random places, depending on what day it is.  They are:

```
Day - Location
  1 - Port Omish
  2 - Grimsby
  3 - Heim
  4 - Oeram
  5 - Barnicia
  6 - Golyat
  7 - Almorica
  8 - Rhime
  9 - Krysaro
 10 - Phidoch
 11 - Balmamusa
 12 - Coitanae
 13 - Asyton
 14 - Brigantys
 15 - Omish
 16 - Grimsby
 17 - Heim
 18 - Oeram
 19 - Barnicia
 20 - Golyat
 21 - Almorica
 22 - Rhime
 23 - Krysaro
 24 - Phidoch
 25 - Balmamusa
```

She sells some rarer spells, but not nearly all of them.  Most of the highest level ones require you to be lucky with drops.  There's a class of magic called Dragon magic that is only available by running through Hell's Gate, as well.

Comment: I don't mind investing time in tedious crafting, so I'll go with that option. I was already using +1 in most of my equipment but the recipes I had only went to weapons and armour level 2; thanks for the link for the locations of the stronger recipes.